# C Program that prints Multiples of 3, 5 and both, professional style suggestion

Tags: c, modulo

I wrote my first simple C program that prints multiples of 3 , 5 and both 3 and 5 instead of the number, from 1 to 100. It works.

I know this program can be written in million different ways. How would a professional C programmer implement best practices? As a perfectionist, I'm trying to implement highest best standards, mainly pointers and professional function implementations and preprocessors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void findMultiples(int n);


int main() {
    
    findMultiples(100);
    
    return 0;
}

void findMultiples(int n){
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        if (i % 15 == 0){
            printf("Multiple of 3 and 5\n");
        }
        else if (i % 5 == 0){
            printf("Multiple of 5\n");
        }
        else if (i % 3 == 0){
            printf("Multiple of 3\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
}
```

Comment: You can fix your indentation a bit, Usually `{` for functions come after the line and for `for` loop with multiple lines, it is encouraged that it is enclosed `{ }`. Another thing, almost a personal preference,  would be to have functions with returning value instead of `void`

Comment: Assuming the code works, then this question as-is, is on-topic and should be asked at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. On SO is is border-line opinion-based and too broad.

Comment: (Though this particular little algorithm is the well-known "Fizz Buzz" one. If you search for "Fizz Buzz optimization" and similar, you'll find plenty of examples online. For example this one for Java on CR: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74443/fizzbuzz-problem-solution)

Comment: you're right. This was a question for a certification evaluation and even though fizz buzz was mentioned I didn't even think to look it up using the actual fizz buzz words online and wrote the code myself. that's Funny!

Comment: The code will do 39 modulo operations for a sequence of 15 consecutive numbers. You could reduce that to 30 modulo operations by always doing the `i % 3 == 0` and `i % 5 == 0` operations and storing their results. (Division and modulo operations are relatively expensive.)

Comment: good call. so, remove %15 == 0 and replace %3== 0 &&  %5 == 0

Comment: `void findMultiples(int n);` bad name... the function does not search for anything anywhere (what "find" implies). I'd name it `printMultiples`. Also it may be a good idea to pass the bases on which multiples are calculated... and return number of multiples printed? `int printMultiples(int limit, int *bases);` This new version could be called as `int p = printMultiples(100, (int[]){3, 5, 0});`

Comment: makes sense, the code is still however looking to find multiples in the numbers, but I get what you're saying pmg

Comment: Could use `tests = (i % 5 == 0)*2 + (i % 3 == 0);` and then `switch(tests)` with 4 cases, or an indexed  string lookup, etc.  Of do both mod tests and set results to flags that are later tested for printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically [Fizzbuzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz) where you should print FizzBuzz if it is dividable by both 5 and 3, Fizz if it is dividable by 5 but not 3 and Buzz if it is dividable by 3 but not 5.

## TL;DR

There is no "right" way to do this. No matter how you do it you will break some best practices.

## Long explanation

> **Note!**
>
> I'm the kind of programmer who prefers a flexible approach to best practices and code standards. This is not right or wrong, but the whole following text is colored by my personality. I pretty much view this test as "can you understand when to skip best practices" while other people would view it like "can you figure out how to follow best practices even in tricky cases". None is more right that the other.

This problem is intended to be very easy to understand, but pretty tricky to do it "nice". One thing you often will encounter in this example is duplicated code. You can quite easily build it away, but often at the cost of readability.

If I were to design a code that did what you ask, I would be perfectly happy with the solution you have provided and then move on to the next problem. It's not really worth spending a lot of time on. That is also a thing employers look at when they give you this test. Do you spend hours and days just to make sure your code follows all "best practices" even if the gain is minuscule or do you create code that works and is readable and move on as soon as it is good enough?

Some examples I have seen to avoid first checking if it is dividable by both numbers and then check them separately is concatenating strings. Something like this pseudo:

```
string str = ""
if n % 5 = 0: str += "Fizz"
if n % 3 = 0: str += "Buzz"
print str
```

Looks nice, right? Well translate it to real C where string handling is pretty messy.

```
char str[9] = "";
if(n%5 == 0) strcat(str, "Fizz");
if(n%3 == 0) strcat(str, "Buzz");
puts(str);
```

Does not look too bad though. But is it really worth it? And what if you want to change "Fizz" and "Buzz" to something longer? Then you need to make sure that `str` has more space, which is easy to forget and can cause hard traced bugs. I'm not saying that this code is extremely dangerous, but the bottom line here is how you reason. Is that risk really, really worth the effort of avoid some code duplication?

Some people refactor out the conditions as functions, like `bool dividable_by_15(int n)` because "it's good to break out functionality in separate functions". Some would even go as far as this:

```
bool dividable_by(int n, int d) { return (n%d) == 0; }
bool dividable_by_3(int n) { return dividable_by(n, 3); }
bool dividable_by_5(int n) { return dividable_by(n, 5); }
bool dividable_by_15(int n) { return dividable_by_3(n) && dividable_by_5(n); }
```

But is it really needed in this case? I don't think so, but I would not say that the choice is 100% obvious, and it also depends on what language you're using. But for most cases I would say that this is a quite clear case of over engineering.

This test is not so much about seeing if you can follow all best practices. It's more of a personality test. Some employers want you to do all sorts of stuff, while others would prefer if you can just leave the code as it is when it does what it should.

When it comes to your code, I actually only have one objection, and that is that you're omitting the braces for the for loop. I'd never do that, except when the body is one simple line. However, I would omit the braces for the if statements. Some people would agree on the last, and some would not. Those who favor always using braces even for single statements often use the argument that it reduces the risk of bugs if you need to add an extra statement in the body. Another argument is consistency, that you always should strive to do the same thing everywhere. In my opinion, those factors are not worth the extra lines, but hey, that's me. You do you.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (i % 15 == 0)
         printf("Multiple of 3 and 5\n");
    else if (i % 5 == 0)
        printf("Multiple of 5\n");
    else if (i % 3 == 0)
        printf("Multiple of 3\n");
    else
        printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

That looks much better to me. I would even consider having the if's as one liners:

```
    if      (i % 15 == 0) printf("Multiple of 3 and 5\n");
    else if (i % 5 == 0)  printf("Multiple of 5\n");
    else if (i % 3 == 0)  printf("Multiple of 3\n");
    else                  printf("%d\n", i);
```

I would also consider extracting the newline, like this:

```
    if      (i % 15 == 0) printf("Multiple of 3 and 5");
    else if (i % 5 == 0)  printf("Multiple of 5");
    else if (i % 3 == 0)  printf("Multiple of 3");
    else                  printf("%d", i);
    printf("\n");
```

Since it's only a new line, you could change `printf("\n")` to just `puts("")`.

BUT - here is the thing - In my opinion, I have already spent far to much energy on this problem. :)

> As a perfectionist, I'm trying to implement highest best standards

I read a quote that answers this perfectly: *"Blindly following best practices is not best practice"*

"Best practices" have the purpose of offering a very simple way to fulfill some goal. If your code fulfill that purpose without following best practices, why change it? Especially if it fulfills that purpose even better.

Comment: Might depend on whether the employer prioritizes quality or time to market.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, I added some emphasis on that too

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that a human is reading the output. Furthermore, the program does not do what you *say* that it does. It does *not* print the multiples of 3 and 5, it *omits* them.

In general I would read what is being asked, then determine how the program is going to be used, and then write the program.
In your case, that would be something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void findMultiples(int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0)) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{   
    findMultiples(100);

    return 0;
}
```

The coding style is not that important.

Now why would I have started with the comment about a human. Well, small programs are usually designed to chain logic. Why would a non-human be interested in the text you print?

I don't think this answer is what you originally had in mind, but I hope it helps you think about your programs in a slightly different way.

Comment: I did want the program to omit the numbers and print only the text. I'll study your code .

Comment: Ah, I see I made a beginner mistake. I quoted you *after* you edited the question. Fortunately everyone can see that.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is the best implementation possible.

To many programmers, it feels unsatisfactory to check the modulo conditions twice, and the implementation of the cases feels like they are so similar that they could be folded together. As such, many of us will try to do tricks to remove the apparent redundancy, somehow.

However, these tricks invariably increase the complexity of the code. The truth is, that the four cases, as you've written them, are very simple to understand. And no trick that you can try to remove the apparent redundancy can make it simpler.

In the end, simplicity trumps smartness. We know this as the KISS principle: Keep It Simple, Stupid. Quality software does not strive to be smart, it strives to be simple. This makes it easier to maintain, easier to extend, and easier to use. **The most important variable to optimize is the simplicity of your code**. The smartest programmers keep their smarts on a short leash, and only release it when required.

---

That said, as purely stylistic comment, it's generally not advisable to omit braces around the body of a complex loop or `if`. I would format your code as:

```
void findMultiples(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (i % 15 == 0) {
            printf("Multiple of 3 and 5\n");
        }
        else if (i % 5 == 0) {
            printf("Multiple of 5\n");
        }
        else if (i % 3 == 0) {
            printf("Multiple of 3\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you always run the risk of messing up what belongs to the loop/if and what does not.

Also, the naming of the function is suboptimal. I think, I would call it something like `printDivisibilityList()`. Because the function does not "find multiples", it prints all numbers and annotates them with their divisibility by `3` and `5`.

Comment: good points. the function name is really something I should have thought of before diving in. this style looks so much cleaner. thanks for the tips